# How do I get to the hidden levels?

Tags: candy-box

By looking at the source, I've found a couple of 'hidden' levels, but not how to get to them. They are as follows:

> desert
>  seas
>  Cow level

How do I get to them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The desert can be reached by using a Get me Out of Here (G.M.O.O.H.) potion.
The things you can possible end up in by using a G.M.O.O.H.-potion are:

> The peaceful forest
> CowLevel
> sea
> desert

They have an equal chance of happening.