# What items are available, and where do you get them?

Tags: candy-box

There are quite a few items available in Candy Box, and I still have three inventory slots left. What all items are there, and where are they all acquired?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On completion, your inventory looks like this:

> [image]

The items are, left-to-right, top-to-bottom:

- The key for the farm - **Forest**
- Armour - decreased damage - **Castle Entrance**
- Horn - faster lollipop production - **Cow level, a random possibility when using a GMOOH potion**
- Swamp Map - **Mount Goblin**
- Boots - faster movement - **Mount Goblin**
- Candy->Lollipop Machine - **Castle Stairs**
- Amulet - faster candy production - **Castle Keep**
- Sorceress Map - **Forest**
- Magicians Hat - Enchant things! - **Underwater**
- Cauldron - Make Potions - **Castle Stairs**
- Finishing Message - **Final level**
- Forge Map - **Underwater**
- Ring - Faster recovery - **Underwater**
- Unicorn Horn - Health Regen - **Castle Keep**
- Finishing Message - **Final Level**
- Well Map - **Underwater**

Answer (score 11):

Where to get (I think I have everything now):

- The key for the farm — Forest
- Armor — Castle entrance
- Horn — Cow level ([G.M.O.O.H. (Get Me Out of Here) potion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116149/4797), finding the level can take many tries)
- Unicorn Horn — Castle Keep
- Amulet — Castle Keep
- Candy Converter — Castle Stairs
- Boots — Mount Goblin
- Swamp Map — Mount Goblin
- Sorceress Map — Forest
- Hat — Underwater
- Ring — Underwater
- Forge Map — Underwater
- Well Map — Underwater
- Cauldron — Castle Stairs

Comment: You can also get boots in the forest.

Comment: swamp map can be gotten in the forest too.