# What is this "Witch" in Candy Box

Tags: candy-box

So, I've been playing this game, Candy Box, for a while now, and I've just recently found this website. While reading the posts, I came across a lot about this "Witch." What is it and how do I find/get it?

Answer (score 2):

The game actually calls her the "Sorceress". To find her, you need the "[map to the sorceress' hut](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116454/4797)", which can be found by playing through The Peaceful Forest level.

[image: map to the sorceress' hut]

After you get the Sorceress Map, just go to your inventory and click on the "*Go to the sorceress' hut*" button.

**The Sorceress**
[image: The Sorceress]

Comment: As your picture shows, it does also call her a witch.

Comment: The map to her hut can also be obtained in Mount Goblin.

Comment: Also you need to chuck some lollipops in her hut to lure her out.

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments says that you get the map by defeating Mount Goblin. You have a fifty percent chance of getting it at Mount Goblin, which decreases by ten percent every time you play again. I just wanted to set straight that you **CAN'T** get it by playing the peaceful forest. This same answer said that you only need one lollipop to draw her out, which is also incorrect. You need to throw in ten.
(No offense is meant by the corrections in this post, it is purely informational. I apologize for any offense that is taken.

Answer (score 0):

You find the map to the sorceress' hut by defeating Mount goblin. It will ask for 1 lollipops to summon the sorceress. The things you can buy from her costs thousands of lollipops, so plant many of them.